# How can I close a question that has an active bounty?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, bounty

This question seems (to me) massively, overly broad [Dynamic UserControls within ASP.NET Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23249342/542251).

But I can't close it as because it has an active bounty. What should be done? Does the posting of the bounty make this question exempt from being closed as too broad? Is it worth moderator flagging since I can't currently close it?

Comment: Twice in the past, I've flagged for moderator attention. I know in one case, the moderator agreed with my flag. In the other case I just lost track of the outcome.

Comment: MSE: [How can we close questions with bounties?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-can-we-close-questions-with-bounties)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You flag it for moderator attention with the *in need of moderator intervention* flag. Something along the lines of:

> This question is way too broad, but I cannot VtC it as such because there is a bounty on it. Can a moderator please remove the bounty? Optionally, close it at the same time, but I'll be happy if that part is left to the community.

Make sure your flag tells the moderators why you need their help.

A bounty on a post doesn't exempt it from being off-topic.

Comment: What if the bounty is not refunded if the question is going to be closed immediately after by the mod? Wouldn't that be more effective at discouraging bounty being thrown around? Currently, bounty is revoked from Answerers when question is deleted - if it's not been answered, it should not be refunded to Askers, right?

Comment: No, if someone repeatedly keeps asking off-topic questions and adding bounties to it, a moderator can take more drastic action. It really is not all that common for people to put bounties on posts that are off-topic. Usually the community has already voted to close such posts before the OP has had a chance to add a bounty in the first place.

Comment: Moderator(s?) appear to disagree with this advice, and may decline such a flag with the explanation _flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention._ See my flag on stackoverflow.com/questions/31487804/

Comment: @Mogsdad: re-reading that flag you didn't follow my advise here. You only explained your opinion of the post, I don't see a *please remove the bounty* request in the flag, so the moderator handling the flag may have misunderstood why you flagged (we can't see that there is an active bounty in the flag dashboard). Looking at the question, it is not a cut and dry off-topic case either. I'd be inclined to leave the post as is and let the bounty run its course, in which case you'd have gotten a custom decline message.

Comment: @Mogsdad: tl-dr; moderators do not disagree with this advice but you need to be clearer in your flag message (*please remove the bounty*), and a moderator can still disagree with the assertion the question requires closing.

Comment: thx, I didn't realize the bounty was invisible. (The link ref was about bounties... But also requires more mod time to follow.)

Comment: And what is next when a mod writes back "please use the standard close reasons to close questions, rather than the 'requires moderator attention' flags"? I pointed out that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50534669/cookie-set-with-javascript-not-persisted-by-safari-ios-after-closing-the-app lacks code it asks about, but protected by a bounty.

Comment: @tevemadar: I've poked the mod that handled that; that's a surprising flag response.

Comment: @tevemadar that was my fault! I'm so sorry. It's a sign I need to slow down, making mistakes like that. You did the right thing

Answer (score 33):

You have three options:

1. **Edit the question** to be on-topic. Worth doing if the question and/or answers are pretty decent, but phrased in a way that's likely to encourage further answers that are spam or otherwise unhelpful.
2. **Flag for moderator attention** and request that the bounty be revoked and the question closed. Useful if the question is awful and attracting bad answers.
3. **Wait a week and then close it.** If it's not awful and not currently attracting awful answers, then give it a week - either it'll get fixed (option #1) or it'll get awful (#2) or nothing will happen and no one will care. A shockingly large portion of the time, no one cares and the author just wasted their bounty instead of writing a better question - this is a Valuable Life Lesson you should be proud to allow someone to learn.

Comment: 2 would have been my choice here, too... Thanks for explaining!

Comment: 2. Are flags on bounty-questions in any way prioritized, or do they drift along with all the rest? Leading to, how long does it take to process them? 3. The less time left on the clock, the more appealing this option gets.

Comment: There's no explicit prioritization, @Deduplicator. If a *lot* of people are flagging a given post, that'll show up more readily - otherwise, it's whenever a mod gets to it. It's not unheard of for flags on bountied questions to be handled after the bounty has already expired (and in some cases, after the question has already been closed). Which is why I emphasize that there should be something critical about the question if you're gonna go that route - closing still isn't a super-downvote, and mods aren't gonna step in if the situation isn't clearly harmful.