# Why can't I vote to close a question that has a bounty on it?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, bounty

I just came across [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28102320/implementation-of-google-cards-material-design-concepts-on-php-html-and-css-leve) that I feel is too broad, opinion-based, and looking for recommendations. When I went to vote to close it I encountered the red warning message: **This question has an open bounty and cannot be closed**

The only other question here on Meta I found that was similar was **[How can I close a question that has an active bounty?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252192/very-broad-question-but-with-a-bounty-what-to-do)**, however it just explains how to flag it for moderator attention, and doesn't actually explain why bountied questions are exempt for close votes.

Hence, my question, why can't I vote to close a question that has a bounty on it?

Answer (score 14):

If a question with a bounty were to be closed, the bounty could no longer be fairly applied. Only answers that got in under the radar will be (auto)-awarded the bounty, and that would not be fair to anyone that may have worked in good faith on a more deserving answer without realising the question was really off-topic.

As such, closing a question with a bounty on it requires intervention; a moderator needs to decide if the bounty should simply be refunded or removed, on a case by case basis.

Comment: If the question were closed, couldn't the bounty be returned to the person who applied it?

Comment: @j08691: that's not up to the community to decide. In some cases the bounty could have been used for malicious purposes (to fund a sockpuppet, for example). Also, with gold-tag-badge dupe hammers, do you really want one community member to unilaterally decide a bounty should be revoked?

Comment: Just to add to this, you can't post a bounty on a question until it's at least two days old, so in theory the community has already had a chance to close a question before the bounty is placed. It shouldn't be necessary to close a bounty question most of the time.

Comment: @j08691 Then you get into abuse territory. "I didn't get any answers, close and reopen my question so I can have my bounty back."

Comment: Interesting. I can definitely see how the gold-tag-badge dupe hammer could be an issue. The odd thing with the two day waiting period is that this particular question seemed to float around for an entire week without any attention (up/down votes) or close votes. It looks like adding a bounty however manages to sidestep the close filters entirely, unless a mod flag is raised.

Comment: @j08691: There will always be a few questions here and there that fly by the community radar, simply because they were posted in less popular tags or during a lull in the Stack Overflow visitor rates (Monday morning 03:00-06:00 UTC springs to mind). I always send a quiet thank-you to the bounty-setter that brought my attention to a question we missed.

Comment: If closing isn't an option on questions with an open bounty, then the close link shouldn't be displayed.

Comment: @j08691: what you get then is that people ask where the close link has gone to. Hiding UI options increases confusion.

Comment: For some it increases confusion, for other it creates frustration. Take for example that shiny new Help & Improvement queue where the flag and close links don't even exist.

Comment: @j08691: the review queue is a completely different context; the difference between a question with a bounty and one without is not so clear.

Comment: I sometimes see questions that has a bounty put by the poster himself. When the question is poorly asked, it looks like the poster is trying to get more attention by offering reputation instead of improving its poorly asked question. In those cases, the comment list is endless and consists in some kind of begging like "what do you want, is it something like this? please do this, and that", but no clear answers. How should one treat questions like this?

Comment: @Frederik.L vote on them accordingly. If off-topic, flag it like described but if just poor quality then that's what voting is for.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is there a feature request somewhere to (temporarily) hide or disable the "close" option on bounties? has this ever been asked? It's a bit misleading and kind of a waste of time, especially for those who are not aware of this. I was only aware myself of this just today when trying to vote to close as too broad on a question. If there isn't a feature request; would you suggest one be asked?

Comment: @Fred-ii-: it'll not fly, for the same reasons hiding the vote buttons on your own posts or for users with < 15 rep won't fly. The UI should remain consistent, if you hide the `close` link you'll get loads of people asking why they can't close a specific post. With the link there, you get instant feedback as to why that doesn't work.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I made an edit to my comment, adding (temporarily disable) if that works. If not, then I guess we're best to leave well enough alone then; it was just a suggestion. It's kind of like the "vote to delete" button, when one already voted to delete but are still presented with a message after reclicking on it.

Comment: Once an answer is posted, then get rid of the close link and any prior votes to close. But as long as no answer has been posted, then I believe the question should be "closable."

Comment: If the answer is to protect work done in good faith, why is this not also applicable to non-bounty questions?

Comment: @JonSG: because questions can be reopened just as easily as they can be closed.