# Why should offering a bounty prevent closure?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, bounty

It appears that you're not allowed to flag a question as off-topic (or even to migrate to a different site) if there is an open bounty on it (for example, I believe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180686/how-do-i-use-put-e-g-before-multiple-cites-in-bibtex) would be better suited on tex.stackexchange.com), *as do two existing votes*.

It almost seems as if the bounty system can be abused to prevent closure of off topic questions?

I'd always taken it that you *pay* your bounty to get a wider audience that may be able to get an answer to your question faster, and in this case, the question came to my attention, but whilst I don't know the answer, I do know that it would be more likely to get a response on the site for tex, but the system doesn't let me help migrate it there (I'm only left with an option to leave a comment, which could be misinterpreted as snarky)

So, should the bounty system be changed to prevent offering bounties on questions with close votes; allowing closure of bountied questions, or something else?

Comment: Also see [Why can't I vote to close a question that has a bounty on it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284941)

Comment: And the post has been around for at least 2 days with only 2 close votes on it, so the community didn't think it was worth closing *that* much. The community *can* be wrong, and the question could have been edited, etc.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was more wanting to see a discussion as to whether the rationale should be changed (as I'd already followed the advice to flag for mod attention)

Comment: That's where the other link comes in. No, I don't think the rationale should be changed. The question got your attention *because of the bounty* didn't it? Bounties bring extra attention, even the poor ones. Make use of it, you'd not have had the opportunity if it wasn't for that bounty...

Comment: But my point is that I can't really make use of the bounty, as I can't get the question moved to the best place without bother the moderators. If I could vote to migrate, there could even be scope for the bounty to migrate with it (with the original end date?). Also seems a little odd that the UI lets you go all the way through the close UI when it could stop me *way* earlier, and remind me that I'm unable to close bountied questions with a handy link to the relevant page in the help section for people that didn't know the reasoning...

Comment: No, you cannot migrate a bounty. That'd be migrating reputation to another site, and you cannot unilaterally foist that on another community. Again, that's *why* we need a moderator to intervene in such cases.

Comment: @MartijnPieters "Bounties bring extra attention, even the poor ones." If the question hasn't had much attention before, I agree. However, if the question already has pending close votes, can we prevent adding bounties to it? For example, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34138314/) has 2 close votes before the bounty happens.

Comment: @approxiblue: not all close votes are valid either; we'd have the problem the other way around. I don't have the numbers, perhaps you could ask a Community Manager to tell us how many questions with pending close votes that then get a bounty on them actually get closed, vs. how many questions have their bounty removed by a moderator to be closed.