# Shouldn't there be a rule to apply bounty "only on question having no close votes"?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, bounty

See this question, *[Android slide over letters to create a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36237760/android-slide-over-letters-to-create-a-word)*

Here, the OP is indirectly asking to give him code for whole app/feature.

Also, that question has already received two close votes, and then bounty applied.

I got some answers here: [Why can't I vote to close a question that has a bounty on it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284941/why-cant-i-vote-to-close-a-question-that-has-a-bounty-on-it)

So even if it has serious reasons to not close it, shouldn't there be a rule to only be able to apply a bounty on questions that have no close votes?

Comment: @AakashM it seems to me that OP here is asking the opposite "Why can users put bounty on a question that has pending close votes?"

Comment: I edited the title of the question, that may help other to differ between the two.

Comment: I want to point out that you currently ask 2 questions that are almost each other's opposites. It might be smart to remove the bit that makes it look like a duplicate of that other post

Comment: Tim is absolutely correct on *Not all close votes are correct.* as there are 9 upvotes 3 downvotes and 1 close votes. So let the moderator decide is the best weapon as suggested in accepted answer.

Comment: One one note - he won't have any reputation left to apply bounties to bad questions if he keeps going that way...

Comment: I think this got three quick close votes from the title given in the Hot Meta Posts, which is different from the title it currently has.

Comment: @BillWoodger That's why I voted to reopen.! :)

Comment: @BillWoodger yes you're right. Which proves the point I made, that not all close votes are correct

Comment: Your choice of accepted answer suggests that this meta post is in fact a duplicate since it appears you weren't actually asking if there should be a rule around placing bounties on questions with pending close votes - you just wanted to know what to do in that particular situation.

Comment: @BoltClock There has been no any other option left to me. I asked the simple thing "Should There Be Any Rule" and I got in response downvotes/closevotes and Moderator flag. That means no one else thinks what I think. So I guess that If anyone else feel the same in future then there should be one straight answer to him that Go and Flag it, rather keeping this question open(not accepting answer).

Comment: Also "My choice" - You might have right or not to see time when answer accepted I don't know, so to tell you when I accepted answer there were ONE only and there for I commented to Tim's answer as well. Please consider whole comments and answer before announcing the judgement.  If you still think the same, you can close/delete I won't mind. Because nothings personal here.

Comment: 12 upvoted 5 downvoted 5 closed 5 reopened and 1 moderator close.

Comment: This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question.<br/>

I did the same, edited and now it's completely different then the link you gave for duplication.

Comment: Yes, I can see the time you accepted SGR's answer and you accepted it several minutes *after* Tim had posted, making that two answers, not one. So if you think you can lie your way out of this, you're sorely mistaken. But since we can't overrule a user's choice of accepted answer, we can only conclude that the question you meant to ask is the same as the duplicate - that which is answered by SGR.

Comment: What? I accepted the answer and then after that "1 new answer to the post" something like this came up. You can't tell someone a lier on a public forum just because you are moderator. I can flag it for being rude and offensive but forgiving you thinking you must be doing some good for SO being a Mod.

Anyways, I made the point, I got the response and that's what is SO for, Thanks and End of discussion.

Comment: Even so, you simply commented on Tim's answer, even stating why you kept SGR's answer accepted. Based on the reasoning you've given I fail to see how your question isn't just a duplicate framed as an altogether different question.

Comment: @BoltClock Please delete this question, I believe in making Internet clean and dont want this type of duplicate and non-useful thread to remain searchable by other. Many voted to close this one and I guess I have low IQ to differentiate between two question which you and others have , So I will improve my self besides

Comment: @BoltClock still, this FR has merits.

Comment: @MKJParekh I were you, I wouldn't accept *any* answer that doesn't address *my* question. SGR doesn't.

Comment: @Braiam: Never said otherwise. You are free to post it separately. This question on the other hand should be edited to reflect the accepted answer, because as it is now they simply don't match up and the OP is intent on keeping the accepted answer.

Comment: Removed accepted check mark, now? and @Braiam I would have not, but some how I got this thought "Accepted answer will point other that What to do in such case, what are the options they have in such case"

Answer (score 10):

> shouldn't there be a rule to apply bounty only on question having no close votes?

No.

People can make mistakes. Not all close votes are correct.

The conclusion that a question should be closed is reached when 5 people vote so, not when 1 or 2 do. A closed question cannot have a bounty, but a question that is not yet closed can. It makes sense.

Comment: I just accepted the other answer by SGR, but I also agree with you. *Not all close votes are correct.*

Comment: @MKJParekh that answer doesn't even address your question. I agree with the content of the answer though.

Comment: As SGR straight away mentioned the only possible action can be taken, and there has been no any comment or answer from any moderator So I assume this is not a big thing to get place into TODO list. I accepted the answer so that other user can know what to do.

Comment: I would agree with this if it weren't for the fact that bounties prevent close votes, i.e., the relationship is not symmetrical: one person's action is able to override the ability of everyone else to even express their judgement. Your reasoning leads much more naturally to the idea that neither close votes nor bounties should interact with the other.

Comment: @JoshCaswell that's true. I only viewed it from 1 perspective while there are 2

Answer (score 2):

Best course of action is to flag for moderator attention if you feel strongly enough it should be closed.

Comment: Yes, I checked that, There in one option **should be closed...** but When I click it Takes me to *Why should this question be closed?* and then the same, Can't close. And I don't find any other option in Flag dialog relevant to my choice.

Comment: @MKJParekh You want the option titled: 'in need of moderator intervention'

Comment: Not sure, Simply wants that can be able to close , *As I guess SO is question answer site and not open source site where you can throw some points and get your work done*.

Comment: @MKJParekh I flagged it for you

Comment: @MKJParekh in most cases a bountied question means that the question is worth keeping (open). It takes more than the opinion of a regular user to close/delete it, which is why you ask for a second opinion in the form of a moderator

Comment: @TimCastelijns I guess you are absolutely right, and there it seem that what I see is not usual case. So there doesn't require any special feature to avoid it. So accepting the above answer and winding up.