# How to handle low quality questions with bounty?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, bounty

This is not a very severe problem but it is for sure a recurring theme. I have the impression that low quality questions are handled completely differently when bountied. Questions, that otherwise would have been downvoted and probably closed in no time, are even upvoted.

Take for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54757848/how-to-implement-and-fire-an-event-when-a-change-occurs-in-a-property-of-t-in) - basically a code-writing request with no effort shown. At present net +2 (3 up, 1 down), I'm pretty sure the same Q with no bounty on it would not have achieved a single upvote, instead many "show at least some effort" comments. Same for the [initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54565145/how-to-implement-and-fire-an-event-when-a-change-occurs-in-a-property-of-t-in) by the same author in the C# tag: No effort, large bounty, net +3.

There may not be many of those questions but with the bounty they are very prominent and get more attention than deserved.

How to handle this kind of question?

Comment: Related: [Why can't I vote to close a question that has a bounty on it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284941/7296893). In an ideal world, bad questions would get closed before they're eligible for a bounty. When they have a bounty they get the attention of a different public, and voting culture changes considerably.

Comment: Also note: your second example is invalid. The bounty there was started _after_ the question gathered 2 upvotes, 1 downvote and an answer, as shown in the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54565145/timeline)

Comment: @ErikA oh I didn't know the timeline feature yet. Yes, bounty was "officially" started and awarded after the question was answered. For some reason the author choose to promise the bounty by an edit instead of really starting a bounty. Maybe to keep the reputation, if the question was not answered?!

Comment: Don't assume malice. The author probably edited that in because he _couldn't_ offer a bounty, because the question didn't exist for 2 days yet. While it's still questionable behavior (making edits about bounties and/or votes is not really acceptable), it's unlikely he wanted to pull some rep trick.

Comment: What do you mean "how do you handle"? You mean closing? Because general voting is not something we can "handle". And your votes are your own. See bad content? Down vote. Me, simple monkey like that.

Comment: @yivi The problem is that the regular downvoting and closing process as it seems doesn't work due to different voting behavior if questions got a bounty. Thus bad questions get more attention than they deserve. And those questions stay on SOF without being of common interest.

Comment: For some egregious cases custom mod flags for bounty un-protection will be honored so that regular close-votes can be used. Although it's a jugement call and many subjective factors will impact the final decision. In the end, "featured" question doesn't mean "good" question. But everybody is free to use their votes as they wish.

Comment: @ErikA are you sure voting culture is often influenced by bounties? It seems to me that a bounty has a similar effect as a link on meta; the question gains exposure and so more voting than usual happens, but not necessarily different voting. The examples presented here are only based on a tiny sprinkling of votes, not really anything conclusive.

Comment: @Gimby It's what I observed in the tags I'm active in: meta tends to expose your post to the most critical people on the site and tends to lead to more critical votes, bounties tend to expose your post to occasional visitors who tend to not be very critical of the content. It's just speculation, though, based on a few observations and no statistics at all.

Comment: And then the META effect kicked in. In the past I flagged some bounty posts that were obviously off-topic for mod attention. Where mods could remove the bounty and close the post. Not sure if that is the right way though.

Comment: I think as long as there is no answer, it should be ok to close those posts. Otherwise it would be kind of unfair for the answering user, as he/she/divers may have invested considerable amount of time given the prospective bounty .

Comment: would you suggest [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54627930) is low quality too? I'm trying to figure out why there hasn't been any comment or answer since I offered a bounty.

Comment: @Snow I think this question is pretty ok, but the topic is probably too special. There are in total only 142 questions in the apache-superset tag and there is likely only little expertise for this on SOF.

Comment: Holy crap literally *every question from the first question's asker* is gimme-teh-codez hot trash.

Comment: Since the bounty is pretty fresh I would mod flag and ask them to end the bounty and refund the rep.  The problem though in this case is it was answered after the bounty was posted.  I'm not sure if the mods will decline the flag for that reason.

Comment: @IanKemp didn't we moderate content, not people ;) But yeah I noticed the same thing.