# Is it right that bounties can protect off-topic questions?

Tags: discussion

I was going to vote to close a question asking for an off-site resource. But I was told by the system that since it has an open bounty, it cannot be closed.

So... all you need to do to ask an off-topic question is offer a bounty for it? Seems odd...

I can't even flag it for a moderator, since the flag is turned into a close vote automatically, which fails.

Comment: Moderators have tools to deal with questions like that.

Comment: The Flag "In Need of Moderator Intervention" gets turned into a close vote?

Comment: I feel this has been asked before.  Time to go duplicate hunting.

Comment: Ok, didn't think of using the "Mod Attn" flag. Good idea.

Comment: [How can I close a question that has an active bounty?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252192/how-can-i-close-a-question-that-has-an-active-bounty)

Comment: `So... all you need to do to ask an off-topic question is offer a bounty for it?` No, not that simple :) OP has to sit with that off-topic question for 2 days before starting a bounty.