# Answered my own question minutes after placing a bounty, what to do with it?

Tags: discussion, bounty, self-answer

So I had [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32271467/solidworks-epdm-api-iedmenumeratorvariable5setvar-not-working-as-expected) about an API that doesn't get a lot of attention on SO.  I let it marinate over the weekend and all day today, didn't get any nibbles (kind of expected) and so I decided to throw a bounty up on it.

Literally minutes after starting the bounty, I stumbled upon an example in a forum I frequent for another similar method on the same object I was trying to use - it made me double check the documentation on my method. Sure enough I was able to solve my own problem, so I self-answered my question.

So now what to do with this open bounty for a question I just answered myself?
I get that the points are gone - that's okay, I read the rules before I started it.  It just seems a shame to let 50 rep wither and die.  I'd like to award it to a random person or something.

I thought about editing the question to something silly and just giving it away to my favorite responses, but that doesn't seem appropriate for this site. Does anyone have any ideas?  Should I just leave the bounty and the question alone?

Comment: I'd wait it out- You never know, a better answer than yours or an alternative solution may come in in the next week. If it does and you feel the answer posted is worthy of the bounty, then award it to them. There's really nothing else you can do otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought about editing the question to something silly and just giving it away to my favorite responses, but that doesn't seem appropriate for this site.

You are correct about that behavior being inappropriate.  You can make *minor* modifications to the question, but that probably won't help you with the "I solved my own question" issue.

---

> Does anyone have any ideas?

That depends on the state of your question and your answer.

If your answer is really fixing a minor typo or something like that, I would custom flag a moderator to remove the bounty and close your question with the "Typographical Error."<sup>1</sup>  Note that the bounty means that you can't close it for that reason yourself.  That's why [you need a custom flag to close the bountied question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252192/4320665).

If the answer is a bit more complicated, such as misunderstanding a concept or feels more like a "gotcha," then I'd self answer with the full explanation.  If anyone else provides a helpful answer, you can award the bounty however you wish.

Based on [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32320043/4320665), it seems that cause of confusion is complex enough to warrant an answer.  It seems like a reasonable mistake to come across.  As such, I'd go with your "Just let it be" option.

---

<sup>1 The full text of that off-topic reason is: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers."</sup>

Comment: I agree it would be more than a simple typo - more of I missed something in the documentation and caught it after seeing someone else's code example.  Could be useful if someone else is struggling with the same problem, so I think it's worth leaving.  I'm just going to sit tight and let it ride. Of note, would love to see The Warlords Of Documentation project realized. I've talked to the woman who writes the EPDM API documentation. It's 99% auto generated, and supported by two people.  I would love to be able to contribute to it :)