# Workflow for closing bounty questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, vote-to-close, bounty

The workflow for closing questions that have active bounties is a little cumbersome...

At the moment if you try to closevote a question with an active bounty you'll see this:

[image]

I would guess that most new users see this message and stop there. More experienced users may know to check Meta, and [Meta will tell them to raise a custom Mod flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252193/1947286). It seems to me that we could eliminate these extra steps by automatically converting these closevotes/flags.

Proposed workflow:

1. Find bad bounty question.
2. Closevote/flag as off-topic, dup, etc.
3. Closevote/flag gets auto-converted to mod flag.

   - Something like:

     > **Bounty Question** - Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must
     >   include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
     >   shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.
     >   Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
     >   readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
     >   example.
4. Mod finds flag in their usual queue.
5. Mod handles flag at their discretion as usual.

<sub>If this seems like an edge case that doesn't come up often enough to warrant a new feature, you're probably not looking at the bounties tab very often.</sub>

Comment: Even if a significant percentage of bountied questions merit closure, *all* bountied questions make up a very, very small percentage of the questions on the site, so it is very much an edge case.

Comment: @Servy I suppose that's a fair point, but given that bounty questions are designed to attract more attention they produce a significant broken window.

Comment: Why does that mean you need a special feature to flag the question instead of just flagging the question?

Comment: @Servy If you try to closevote a bounty question at the moment you get a nice little tooltip that reads "This question has an open bounty and can not be closed"

Comment: Why waste a close vote when you can mod flag already?

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-can-we-close-questions-with-bounties. It seems like the consensus would be to just flag normally.

Comment: @Servy I guess what I'm trying to say is that the current workflow isn't as obvious as it could be and requiring the extended workflow seems unnecessary, streamlining the process could remove some of these broken windows.

Comment: @apaul34208 And what I'm trying to say is that it's an edge case, and thus doesn't merit that level of attention.  I'd rather just see the error message edited to mention the possibility of flagging.

Comment: This request actually adds a step to the existing workflow of 1) find bad bountied question 2) flag for moderator 3) moderator finds the flag in their queue 4) moderator handles the flag at their discretion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is an overly complicated request so I'm going to [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) this for the time-being.   If you run across a bounty question that needs to be closed, it's really easy to raise a moderator flag requesting them to review the question, remove the bounty, and then close the question if they feel it's needed.

It's such a small percentage of questions that fall into this category, that your request feels like too much work for very little gain.

I ran a [quick query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/362077/questions-closed-post-bounty) to see how many bounty questions get closed and the percentage is incredibly small.  In the past year we've had **21,204 questions with a bounty** and of those only **98 questions have been closed**, so we're talking about less than 1% of questions that got a bounty were eventually closed.  This doesn't seem worth the development time for such a small impact.

Comment: It seems too me that the provided statistics could as well indicate that the process of closing questions with bounties is overly complicated. What would actually be interesting to know is how many people tried to raise a close flag on questions with bounties (and thus failed).