# Change the bounty closevote tooltip

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, bounty, error-message

I originally hoped to eliminate the message entirely by [automating the process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305587/workflow-for-closing-bounty-questions), but it looks like that may not gain any ground. Failing that could we at least change the message displayed when users try to closevote/flag bounty questions?

The current message reads:

"This question has an open bounty and cannot be closed"

[image]

Perhaps it should read:

"This question has an open bounty and cannot be closed in the usual way, flag for moderator intervention if you think this question should be closed"

The wording could probably use some work...

The current message isn't really accurate. Moderators can and do close questions with open bounties.

Comment: I do feel that the current message is clear enough. Of course moderators can still close them. Also the SE staff can do what they wish to any question and there is no need to say that out loud either.

Comment: @sanfor The goal is to get bad questions with open bounties seen by a moderator. With the current message newer users may not think to raise a mod flag, unless they research the issue on meta.

Comment: @apaul34208  I'm not so sure that moderator invention is even needed. The community will handle that, when the bounty is over. If the question is of no value it will receive close votes, and probably gets deleted over time. Flagging for moderator attention should be used for exceptional cases only.

Answer (score 7):

> The current message isn't really accurate. Moderators can and do close questions with open bounties.

If you wanna talk accuracy, that's not entirely accurate either. We cannot close questions with open bounties. In fact, we get the exact same error message that you do when we attempt to close a bountied question.

The bounty needs to go away first, and as a sanity check the system requires that we refund it separately rather than refunding it automatically with a close vote.

And not all questions with open bounties have to be closed right away. Questions that are either unclear, or duplicates don't have to be closed ASAP — and if users have already answered then it'd be unfair to them to remove the bounty well in its course. Only questions that are strictly off-topic, spam, abusive or otherwise inappropriate are grounds for expedited bounty removal and subsequent closure.

Comment: In addition, a question must survive its first 48 hours before a bounty can be added (IIRC), so it doesn't happen that often.

Comment: @user000001 It's actually not uncommon at all for a really bad question to just not get much traffic at all, and as such not get closed as it just isn't seen by [enough] people with VTC permissions in that time period.

Comment: 6 vs half dozen...

Comment: Isn't that a bit like saying that you can't take off your socks because you must first remove your shoes?

Comment: @apaul34208: Well, not quite. The system makes us stop and think twice about removing a bounty before allowing us to close a bountied question for a reason.

Comment: I get that. Still thinking that an area of the site that is designed to attract attention should get more curating not less. Not sure how to approach it at this point though. Seems most people are OK with the status quo, perhaps I'm making it more of an issue than it needs to be.