# Flagged a Bounty Question as Off-Topic, Flag Declined

Tags: discussion, specific-question, bounty, declined-flags

As per [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252192/2415822), I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32849612/2415822) bounty question for moderator attention as off-topic, yet the flag was declined.

[image: flag]

I had flagged another off-topic bounty question earlier that day, and the flag was marked as helpful.

[image: flag2]

[(link for 10k+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26862931/paypal-payment-user-to-user-in-app)

Was I wrong to flag this question? To me, it is off topic because it is too broad and does not provide an MCVE. It's a "give me teh codes" question.

Comment: Likely a moderator that disagreed with you. I wouldn't worry about it. I kind of disagree that it's a "give me the codes" kind of question though.

Comment: @Zizouz212 I'm certain that's the case, since I flagged for moderator attention.  The question is why?  And do others agree with the declined flag reason?

Comment: Flags are handled by a sole diamond moderator, not 10k users or anything. The mod disagreed that the question should be closed - it asks more for a best practice then simply to give the code.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Even so, a "best practice" question is still off-topic as primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 8):

> How should I modify it so that I can pass `std::array`s, `std::vector`s or even `std::list`s and get them sorted as well?

If this is primarily opinion-based, then so is literally every single how-to question on the site. There are often many ways to do something, and all questions of this nature imply "best practices" somehow (this is why we have a voting system!), but that doesn't make that thing inherently opinion-based. That the OP hasn't shown what they've tried doesn't make it off-topic either.

Bounties protect questions from closure for a reason. The lack of an MCVE can *easily* be fixed either by the OP or by an editor depending on the circumstances. In this case, it looks like the code from the linked Code Review question could be carried over without having to go to the trouble of

1. removing the bounty and notice,
2. reimbursing the OP the bounty rep,
3. closing the question,
4. waiting for the issue to be fixed,
5. reopening the question, and
6. having the OP set the bounty *again*.

If no one will fix the issue, then the bounty will expire or auto-award as normal and once that happens you can vote to close it however you like. If the OP doesn't get a satisfactory answer because of this, too bad for them.

Moderators only close bountied questions that warrant immediate closure (and possibly deletion) for exceptional reasons, such as being *blatantly* off-topic so as to be unsalvageable (like the question you had flagged previously that's now deleted).

Comment: Probably noteworthy: If the offsite sources license was not obviously compatible, the code could not simply be imported.