# Is it okay to bring a specific question to the attention of meta?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, downvotes

I have seen several questions here on meta in the form of: *"Is this (non-meta) question okay?"*, but in this case I am positive that the question is low quality an should be closed (basically, the question goes like "why isn't this code working?" without a single line of code inside).

I cannot vote to close it because of an active bounty.

I tried to reach to the author, but he has ignored me so far. Au contraire, and to my dismay, the question has already received 6 (!) up-votes, although my comments asking for improvement has been deemed useful four times.

Now, there is a high-visibility, low-quality question hanging there, asked by a high-rep user, mind you.

In my opinion this is unfair because high-rep users can go away with poor questions: just throw a 500 rep bounty and save it from closure until some rep-whore, such as myself, will answer eventually. This is also harmful to the site because it seems to convey the message that such questions are welcome on SO.

<sup>*Allright, I must confess I am also a bit pissed off because the OP has ignored everyone in in the thread, including myself who even took the time to try to answer his crappy question...*</sup>

Will I be frowned upon if I asked meta to down-vote this question as deserved?

If this is inappropriate an action, is there anything else I can do to see the question gone ASAP? Do I just need to wait until the bounty expires so that I can vote to close.

Comment: Umm.... what question?

Comment: Well the thing is I don't really want to attract too much attention to the actual question until I know it is right to do so. What question it is does not matter, I believe. It really is: "I got this error" without a piece of code, just an excerpt from some manual, and an error message. My question is basically: is it okay to mention the actual question here?

Comment: I remember some people may take a screen cap for the actual question and then mask all names manually, but not sure if it is encouraged.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a fine line between asking a question on meta for a specific question and grandstanding on meta to solicit support.

The former is acceptable because you are asking about a specific question that may or may not be on-topic and you need clarification about its fitness for the site.

The latter is just abuse.  When someone tries to post numerous questions on meta about bad questions in an effort to solicit support to close the question, then they are not using meta the way it was intended.

So the easiest answer to your problem is ask yourself "why am I asking this question".  If you are asking it because you "know" the answer is off-topic and you want to draw attention to it to get it closed quickly, then asking on meta is not appropriate.  But if the question is not a cut and dry problem, and you need some clarification as to why a question is on or offtopic, then asking on meta for clarification purposes is perfectly acceptable.

Consider it this way, what if everyone who wanted a question gone were to post on meta.  Meta would just be overrun with "close this please" questions.  If only there was a way to organize questions with close votes that would allow users who can and want to close questions can review them and vote to keep them open or close them (and even filter them based on the tags on the question).  Hmmmmm..... sounds a lot like the [Close Vote Review Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close).  When you vote to close a question, it ends up here.  Yes it has its problems, and yes, it is currently 8.6K questions large, but it is still the best place for reviewing questions that need closed.

Bounty questions, however, pose a different problem since no one can vote to close them.  A moderator is first required to refund the bounty, and then close it.  The bounty issue is better explained in [How can I close a question that has an active bounty?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252192/how-can-i-close-a-question-that-has-an-active-bounty4).

When you have a bounty, you have three options ([according to Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252192/how-can-i-close-a-question-that-has-an-active-bounty/308724#308724)):

> - Edit the question to be on-topic. Worth doing if the question and/or answers are pretty decent, but phrased in a way that's likely to encourage further answers that are spam or otherwise unhelpful.
> - Flag for moderator attention and request that the bounty be revoked and the question closed. Useful if the question is awful and attracting bad answers.
> - Wait a week and then close it. If it's not awful and not currently attracting awful answers, then give it a week - either it'll get fixed (option #1) or it'll get awful (#2) or nothing will happen and no one will care. A shockingly large portion of the time, no one cares and the author just wasted their bounty instead of writing a better question - this is a Valuable Life Lesson you should be proud to allow someone to learn.

So consider this.... if you really want to "punish" the author of your horrible post for not improving it, the best thing might be to let the bounty run its course.  He'll lose his rep and the question will be closed.  If you try to close it early, a mod will have to refund the bounty first before closing.

Comment: I am clearly in your second case. I *know* for sure the question should be closed. I would vote as such if the system allowed. I would prefer to see the question improved, but it is not happening. Now I want the question gone, and it seems that some people agree with me. What are the options?

Comment: @RandomSeed consider the fact that if everyone who wanted a question gone would post on meta, what would meta become?

Comment: @RandomSeed: Simply speaking, you can flag it for the mods if the bounty still has lots of time on its clock and it's a clear-cut case. But mention that it has a bounty, and what you want to happen and why. Otherwise, just let it run out and then do the right thing.

Comment: @RandomSeed I've update my answer to better address the bounty question.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it seems that quite resolves the question... I am afraid I disagree with this strategy. I believe the community should be able to VTC a question even if it has a bounty, and the second best available action IMO  is voting down the question. But this is another story.

Comment: Oh and my goal is not that the author looses its rep. I am sure he does not care either, since he spent 500 rep on the bounty (that's 250 down votes worth :)

Answer (score 2):

If it's clearly low quality, but you can't VTC, then the next best thing you can do is to *flag it*. Make sure you mention the open bounty preventing you from VTCing it. If a mod agrees that it needs closing and/or deleting, then they can do that (I believe this also automatically clears the bounty).

Asking on meta for this kind of thing. Questions about "is this question off-topic" should be about clarifying ambiguous cases, especially since *that is something the community can help with*. But most of us here don't have any more power than you to VTC a bountied question. Flagging for moderator attention is the quickest way to get it to the attention of people who *can* do more than you about it.

Comment: Right, only a mod can close a question with a bounty. But anyone else can vote on a question if it is "not useful", which I believe is the most appropriate action (besides calling for a mod). Oh I hope the communty could handle these cases by it self without involving a mod.