# Are questions that ask for clarification on non-programming documentation off-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, bounty, declined-flags

I recently [found a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37048466/2415822) which asks for the definition of a word in Apple's Human Interface Guidelines.  To me, this question is off-topic.

1. It is not a programming question.
2. It is asking for the definition of an English word (in a mobile UI sense).
3. It is [potentially] opinion-based since the interpretation of the word may vary.  Only Apple knows the "true" definition in this context since they wrote the document, and a direct inquiry on an Apple support forum would give a more explicit (and subjectively correct) answer.
4. It is a UX question and may be better suite for [UX.SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) if it were edited to be less broad.

Due to the bounty on the question, I was unable to vote to close the question.  I mod flagged for closure with this reason:

> This bounty question is not a programming question, but a question about the wording in Apple's Human Interface Guidelines about UI wording. I cannot vote to close this question due to the bounty attached.

The mod response:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Are questions about Apple's Human Interface Guidelines, or other design documentation (non-technical) off-topic for Stack Overflow?

Comment: That's what [UX.SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) is for...

Comment: Maybe my threshold for trash has been significantly lowered over the past two years, but it strikes me as rather important that any [ios] programmer should understand the UI guidelines.  The question is crystal-clear.  Then again, odd that it hasn't been answered yet.  Hmm.  Well, it has a bounty on it, no way it is going to get closed now.

Comment: Question posters must wait two days before they can post a bounty.  In that time, not a single user with close-vote privileges opted to cast a close vote on that question, so.

Comment: @RobertHarvey just because the question fell through the cracks of community moderation does not mean that it is not off-topic.

Comment: No, but it does mean that there is not strong motivation from the community to do anything about it.  The question is not even controversial; controversial questions get close votes, downvotes, upvotes and numerous comments.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Give me infinite close votes and downvotes, and I'll show you strong motivation.

Comment: I fail to see how a question about a technical term in official IOS guidelines regarding user interfaces is off-topic on tags for `ios` and `user-interface`. I think that it is rather obviously on-topic.

Comment: Very related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252192/how-can-i-close-a-question-that-has-an-active-bounty/308724#308724

Answer (score 10):

> It is not a programming question.

Only in the sense that it does not involve a specific piece of code. It does involve design practice, which must be implemented by a programmer, as specified by Apple's guidelines. To me, this question is no different than someone asking about the behavior of the OpenGL tessellation system.

They're not programming per-se, but the answers will certainly inform programmers about how to do their job.

> It is asking for the definition of an English word (in a mobile UI sense).

So is "what does 'vertex' refer to," but that would be a valid question about some portion of the OpenGL specification. Especially when you provide a quote from said specification that shows the context the term is used in.

> It is [potentially] opinion-based since the interpretation of the word may vary. Only Apple knows the "true" definition in this context since they wrote the document, and a direct inquiry on an Apple support forum would give a more explicit (and subjectively correct) answer.

I don't know anything about iOS development. But just from reading the question, I don't get that sense. The use of the term "inspector" in the document seems to suggest that it is something which can be "implemented". That sounds like a real, objective concept. I have no reason to assume that there is no definition behind the use of that term.

So I would say that you need to provide evidence that there is no such objective definition.

Furthermore, asking about interpretations of documents related to programming has a *very* long history on this site. Indeed, this question seems better than the common "why does the C++ spec do forbid X" style questions.

> It is a UX question and may be better suite for UX.SE if it were edited to be less broad.

Maybe. But that doesn't mean it isn't on-topic for SO.

> Are questions about Apple's Human Interface Guidelines, or other design documentation (non-technical) off-topic for Stack Overflow?

I say that it should be looked at on a case-by-case basis. How important to an iOS developer are Apple's Human Interface Guidelines? Will an incorrect implementation of them cause a programmer's iOS app to fail to be published? How important is maintaining a consistent look-and-feel to Apple users, and therefore to programmers making apps for them?

It is not unreasonable for interface guidelines to be considered programmer documentation as much as UX documentation.

Comment: About the vertex sample, a simplier way to demonstrate the point, would be to consider that a programmer can't use an API/framework if he doesn't understand the concepts/objects behind it. So a programmer can't use a vertex properly if he doesn't understand what it means. And i think people will be more happy to answer to "what is a vertex ? i don't understand it" to a low quality question from sommeone who don't understand the basics of what he's trying. And such content is so more valuable to SO.