# Same person offers bounty and answers question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, bounty

[This happened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40460701/why-cant-i-define-an-array-size-using-define-constant).  Someone answered a question and also offered a bounty.

The answer was posted 4 minutes after the question, so I don't think it is a case of offering a bounty and later coming to realize knowing the answer. OP must have intended to do this.

However this has the side-effect that the question cannot now be closed as duplicate, despite the fact that it is a duplicate. This same question gets asked regularly, there are many duplicates.

Is there any legitimate purpose to both offering a bounty and answering it? It seems to me that the answerer has used this as a loophole in the system to gain reputation.  If the question is closed as duplicate it will stop getting visibility and therefore votes.  But now the guy has got a whole bunch of rep for repeating an answer that already exists many times on the site.

Surely the better outcome would be marking the question as duplicate, and the answerer could have posted the answer on the duplicate.

Comment: 24 votes for a typo question, tsk, tsk.  This site is not what it used to be, but that can't be helped.  It is only as good as the users make it and they aim low these days.  You can close it in 2 days, max.

Comment: Define "just now" in this context. On another bountied question by that user there is reference to their "bounty campaign" and a suggestion to another user to swap bounties. Perhaps a conversation with the powers that be can ensure that the user is not, accidentally or deliberately, using bounties outside their spirit. So, a flag.

Comment: @BillWoodger "just now" = I noticed it just now... have removed that wording.  Good find about the bounty-gaming.

Comment: I'd not call it outright "gaming" for now, they claim to be keen on highlighting NPE because it happens a lot. Not sure I accept that, but even if it is the case they are perhaps unaware that bounties are not "designed" to highlight general aspects, but specific questions. It could be coincidence that they are in profit, and so many votes on the answer are likely due to the presence of the bounty.

Comment: I've removed the bounty and closed that question as a dupe of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735099/why-does-define-not-require-a-semicolon) because it was the better option (instead of closing it as a typo)

Comment: Hmm, nice, he got the +100 rep earned while it was in bounty *and* he got his bounty back.  I'll have to remember that one for a rainy day :)

Comment: It certainly feels like an attempt at repwhoooooh, er, yeah, rep farming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It seems to me that the answerer has used this as a loophole in the system to gain reputation.

That might be true; therefore, the minimum bounty on a question you already posted an answer to is [100 instead of 50](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

> However this has the side-effect that the question cannot now be closed as duplicate, despite the fact that it is a duplicate.

The way to go is to [flag the question for moderation attention](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252192/how-can-i-close-a-question-that-has-an-active-bounty), explaining *why* it is a duplicate. If they agree, they will usually revert the bounty and close the question.