# Is it OK for posters to ask for code to be written in exchange for a bounty?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43488462/create-new-typo3-backend-module-menu-group).

Normally, I could imagine this getting downvotes because there seems to be little or no effort in researching and really is just asking for someone to 'write the code' for the OP.

But it has a substantial bounty on it, which appears to be a sort of 'payment' for the best code solution to the question.

The presence of the bounty, for some reason (in my head at least), seems to cloud my opinion on its validity.

Should we vote to close as its clearly poor quality?

Comment: That's not really a write-code-for-me question. It is asking how to approach a problem. That people actually write code to illustrate their approach is fine. Got any better examples? Note that you *can't vote to close questions with a bounty*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What would you say about [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43425994/6214222)? They don't directly ask someone to write a whole shader for them, but instead they want someone to *help and point (them) into the right direction*. I'm pretty sure this would fall under *too broad* (I'd also say this about the question linked in this post). Does the bounty somehow raise the bar for closing questions that are too broad or am I just wrong in my assessment that both of these questions would rightfully get closed under normal circumstances?

Comment: No, bounties do not raise the bar. If a post is off topic it is off topic. See [How can I close a question that has an active bounty?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252192) on how to ask for moderator intervention for posts you feel should be closed instead.

Comment: Thanks @halfer for letting me know about this.Im the poster of the question mentioned and I dont see how that would be a "write-a-code" question.I have never asked for code nor will I ever do so! The solutions shown do not work in my case (or I'm thinking in different direction and just cant understand them) and since the Typo3 documentation is more then the just poor I set up a bounty in hope more people will comment and help me understand. I agree, that this would be more of a forum type question,but the Typo3 community directs me here for all issues now.I'm sorry if I caused some confusion.

Answer (score 5):

> Should we vote to close as its clearly poor quality?

Poor quality is not an off-topic reason. Use *voting* for that.

Other than that, bounties do not somehow make a question less off-topic. If a post is off-topic, the presence of an active bounty *doesn't matter*.

The only thing a bounty does, is make it a little harder to close (a moderator must get involved). See [How can I close a question that has an active bounty?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252192/how-can-i-close-a-question-that-has-an-active-bounty)