# Bounty system overriding moderator rights

Tags: discussion, bug, vote-to-close, bounty

Whenever someone posts a bounty on a question, it immediately overrides all possibilities for users to moderate that post. Users can no longer cast close votes - they can no longer even *see* already cast close votes. Gold badge users can no longer dupehammer.

I believe this is some sort of design-by-accident, as there is no reason why a question that gets a bounty from any random user would be guaranteed to have higher standards than other questions.

This could in fact easily be abused as an exploit to prevent your questions from getting closed by anyone but a diamond mod. The only option left for users, no matter their rep and previligies, is to flag.

The bounty system is already a rather questionable site feature, not anywhere near as important as user moderation. So perhaps we could disable the bounty system entirely, until someone has fixed this (old) bug, so that we can moderate posts with bounties just like any other post?

Comment: Disabling the entire system because of one flaw sounds a bit like throwing the baby out with the bathwater, but being able to close-vote a bountied question would be a nice feature. Do note that there should be at least a handful of duplicates for this on meta already.

Comment: See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252192/how-can-i-close-a-question-that-has-an-active-bounty) for example, the current solution is to flag those questions.

Comment: @ivarni It is a weird system that goes against the whole idea of reputation being a way to measure the community's trust in one user, so disabling or removing the system is a good thing. Anyway, that duplicate is **four years old**. I already mentioned that this exploit is old and well-known. Yet nobody is fixing it.

Comment: @Lundin Hence me not voting to close and just providing the link. I kinda agree that this bounty-immunity isn't great but I don't think removing the entire mechanism is a very good solution either. The current workaround with flagging goes a little way towards solving this, it just potentially takes a bit more time than getting 5 CVs

Comment: Who is using the bounty system to prevent their questions from being closed?

Comment: @ivarni The purpose is mainly to lower the workload for diamond moderators.

Comment: It would be interesting to see how often bountied questions are custom-flagged then, if that data is available to us. That would give some indication of how big this problem is.

Comment: @Lundin - The duplicate target mentioned was Shog9 stating that this wasn't a problem. It was from 2 years and 4 months ago. He is probably in a much better vantage point to discern that. Moreover, he would definitely be more informed of the workload required, which is non-existent compared to other issues that face moderators in my opinion. I don't see what has changed that would not make this a duplicate of the existing outlook.

Comment: The outlook hasn't changed since 2009. [Atwood 09](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27103/178816): custom flag it for a moderator, [Gravell 09](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27093/178816): custom flag it for a moderator, [Harvey 11](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97361/178816): custom flag it for a moderator, [Martijn 14](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252193/1026459): custom flag it for a moderator, [Shog9 12](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137432/178816),[Shog9 15](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308724/1026459): custom flag it for a moderator or wait and close it.

Comment: Moreover, Shog9 also rather [strongly states](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140566/178816) "Once a bounty has been offered on a question, if that question needs to be closed then a moderator needs to be involved." on a post from 2012 where he has commented as recently as 2016. This issue has been beaten to death and always results in the same outcome.

Comment: This is not a design by accident, it is quite deliberate. When a bounty has been added the visibility of a post shoots up, and with that visibility comes attention from a much broader audience. By limiting moderation actions to the moderators alone, we get to diminish the effect of the larger herd of users coming in.

Comment: This is indeed a feechur; it's been brought up more than a few times on MSE. For example: [Allow users to vote to close bountied questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121448); [Please stop bounties from turning off community moderation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142482) and the even more simple and reasonable [Close votes shouldn't expire on bountied questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120675).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Perhaps a part of the underlying problem here is that, at least in my experience, bounties *don't* really do a very good job of making questions more visible. Not even close to the way that e.g. HNQ or the meta effect do. Now, if bountied questions were, say, shown in the sidebar...

Comment: @Ilmari currently 340 bounties on stack. One helluva sidebar you have....

Comment: @Patrice: Well, yeah, that's one reason why bounties don't attract that much attention nowadays. There's just too many of them. But I guess if the sidebar idea was actually implemented, it could sample just a few of them each time, just like the HNQ sidebar does. Maybe even bias the selection based on the size of the bounty and other stuff (score, tags, answers, time remaining, etc.).

Comment: ... But what I was really trying to point out is that any argument that starts from the premise that questions with bounties currently get a lot of extra attention from experienced users is likely to be flawed. They're meant to, but I'm not convinced that they actually do, at least not here on SO.

Answer (score -7):

There is no water-tight solution. But, as is [pointed out by Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252193/812149), a bounty does not exempt a question from being off-topic.

On the other hand, somebody invested points in the question. If we allowed people to Close the question none-the-less, that would be a waste of points. And since gold badge holders can close a question single-handedly, there is opportunity for abuse.

My suggestion is to let the Close Votes count - but only actually close the question as soon as the bounty expires (after the grace period).
Then, we know our Close Votes are recorded. It may save some custom mod flags, and the question still gets the attention that the bounty poster paid for.

If a bountied question needs closing urgently, we can still use a custom moderator flag. Otherwise, this system lets the community close the bountied question, saving the moderators a little workload.

Comment: What would be the point of allowing answers if the question will be closed the moment the bounty is finished? The then pending closure, if anything, is an indication that the question shouldn't be answered...

Comment: @Cerbrus The person posting the bounty believes the question shouldn't just be open, but even invested points in the hope of getting an answer. The person voting to close believes it should be closed. Either of them could be right, but the first one invested a lot more. If the question isn't getting a lot of exposure even with the bounty, we might as well let the bounty poster give what little exposure they paid for.