# Veteran users should not get to unilaterally dupe-hammer Meta contributions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, meta, dupehammer

I have noticed lately that trying to start a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) on meta isn't as fruitful as it used to be. Once, any member of the community, no matter reputation, could raise a discussion and anyone with an opinion of the topic could participate. All according to basic democratic principles of freedom of speech and equality.

Not so much anymore, because of the dupe hammer. Some meta users have participated enough that they now start to get gold badges in tags like [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request). No wonder, since these tags are mandatory.

On several occasions I have had my attempts to raise an open discussion closed by some meta-lurker who is *master of discussion* and therefore apparently above everyone else, giving themselves the right to dupe hammer and kill any discussion they don't like, as a duplicate to some generic meta thread which may or may not address the issue. I'd link some examples, but they have apparently been deleted by Roomba.

I am a veteran user and fairly aware of all site policies, both on meta and the main site. Yet a *master of discussion* can at any point take the right to close  my posts and dismiss them. Then imagine how hard it must be to make your voice heard if you are a new user who has not participated on meta forever.

This was never the intention of the dupe hammer. The intention was that people with a certain **technical** expertise would be allowed to close down FAQs on the *main site*. Not to make some users worth more than others, or to create an elite caste on meta.

This is anti-democratic, it is elitism and a form of abuse. The dupe hammer does not make the slightest sense on meta, so why is it allowed? The obvious thing to do is to disable it for all of meta.

---

One specific example of abuse is found [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360720/cleaning-up-a-canonical-post-about-the-format-of-main-c-and-c), where a very specific question (that took a lot of effort to write) about cleaning up trash answers that clutter down a C and C++ canonical duplicate, was closed down by a gold badge [support](/questions/tagged/support) user 5 minutes after posting as a duplicate to the very generic [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer). Supposedly because said user did not wish to discuss it.

Comment: Is this technically not a feature request?

Comment: @Justastudent Yeah probably. I'm reluctant to expose the question to more of the mandatory tags, for the mentioned reasons... but sure I'll add that, and we'll see if Master of Feature-Requests approves.

Comment: `giving themselves the right` well, not really. It's the *system* that gives them the right and there's nothing they can do about it. And it would be very unfair to ask the most experienced users from dupe-voting (which is absolutely needed around here) just because the system is giving them powers they may not even have wanted. I'd absolutely support a feature request to disable the dupe hammer on Meta to fix this (but then thsi question should probably be retitled to reflect the exact feature request)

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your question, but isn't the point of closing as a dupe to encourage discussion of a topic in _one place_ instead of spreading it across several questions?

Comment: @Pekka웃 If they close your discussion as a duplicate to a generic meta post, rather than a duplicate to a specific issue, then they give themselves the right to close the discussion. I had a perfect example of this, which was deleted.

Comment: @Modus the issue is that some users have the "dupe hammer" that allows them to unilaterally close a question. That's not ideal on a discussion platform like Meta (although there *are* lots of legitimate duplicate closings.)

Comment: `If they close your discussion as a duplicate to a generic meta post` whether that's the right thing to do or not is often in the eye of the beholder, though. Which is arguably why the community should work it out (by finding 5 people to vote one way or the other, like on the main site).

Comment: @Pekka웃 The question makes it sound as if those questions are closed with malicious intent, and I doubt that. Also, questions can be reopened, right? Do we really have a problem here?

Comment: @ModusTollens Lets say I want to raise discussion about existing meta policies. Then the Master of Discussion closes my discussion with a link to the existing meta policies. Between the lines: "This is the policies. End of story."

Comment: To note, this is clearly in response to my closure of your question about users not being able to close questions which have open bounties. I am sorry that you feel that was "killing discussion", but perhaps you could participate in one of the other dozen actively open posts about that topic which already exist? Anyway, for those interested, please visit the post that spawned this post here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363064/1026459

Comment: I'm not sure whether using hyperbole sarcastic epithets like "Master of Discussion" is terribly useful here. Meta gets a lot of content that does need and deserve closing because it's been discussed hundreds of times over already. The veteran users do play a role in moderating this content and it's not terribly fun work. Some of those users are too zealous/jaded/heavy-handed and deserve criticism but this idea that they're all inherently some kind of authoritarian sociopath is incredibly tiring.

Comment: @TravisJ No it is actually not, though that was what finally triggered me to write this. If that close vote was the reason I would have linked it as an example. I've had much worse examples in the past months but ignored it then. The linked thread is a very specific issue, so your close vote may or may not have been correct. We can't tell, since there was no consensus of 5 meta users to close the post, which is unfortunate.

Comment: @Pekka웃 We can't ignore the fact that there is a lot of users who do nothing but participate the meta, to the point where they actually don't use the main site. "Master of Discussion" is a suitable epithet since many on meta have wandered so far away from technical programming Q&A, that they might have forgotten that's what this site is for.

Comment: `many on meta have wandered far away from technical programming Q&A`  yes; so have I. What exactly is wrong with that and why does it make me deserving of your epithet?

Comment: Oh, okay, well then who of the other 18 users is it? [The list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/100/discussion) is rather small. This example was only the third time I have used the dupehammer closure tool.

Comment: Lundin, you've started with a valid point, one I think many may agree (_Mjölnir_ not being entirely as apt for meta as for main), but you veering into personal attacks isn't doing anything good to drive your point forward. Which is a shame, because it did start as useful discussion.

Comment: I edited the title to reflect the feature request; feel free to roll back if you don't like it.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Mostly the problem is that those who don't participate on the main site will lose touch with the actual community, which is located on SO and not on meta. You can only notice frequent problems and trends in the ever-shifting community if you are actively a part of it.

Comment: @TravisJ It adds nothing to point fingers at people here. This problem will however only grow, the more people that are getting the badges.

Comment: If it adds nothing, then please, remove it from your post.

Comment: `those who don't participate on the main site will lose touch with the actual community` True in some areas, not really true in others. I'm out of touch on a lot of new developments on the site (and on Meta really). Doesn't mean I can't dupe-close the 2,000th request for making comments mandatory on downvotes, or some other idea or request that has dozens of dupes and doesn't add anything new to the table. I do, as said, support the idea of removing the dupe-hammer from Meta. But it doesn't need the epithets and from experience, feature requests generally fare better without them

Comment: @TravisJ Which user did I name or point fingers at?

Comment: `some meta-lurker who is master of discussion and therefore apparently above everyone else, giving themselves the right to dupe hammer` ` a form of abuse` is pointing fingers, especially when the list of people with the power is so small. Unnecessary and antagonizing. I'd be happy to suggest a more neutral edit for this if you want, to give it a better chance to do well in terms of votes (which doesn't mean anything will actually ever be done about it, of course... but that is not in our hands.)

Comment: Agree with the requested feature, don't agree with how the feature request is written. If you get it in a neutral form that is on point (without all the ranting) then I would upvote it.

Comment: Bear in mind that MSO is probably the only (citation needed) child meta that actually has users with gold badges in the compulsory tags - of which a significant amount are either CMs/current moderators (who don't need the badge anyway) or former moderators (who've been around enough to have "seen it (several times) before and know how it goes") - so special casing removing the ability for users one can count using your fingers when there's no evidence of malicious intent, that in cases I've seen is actually useful, and things can be reopened if needed - I can't quite get behind this idea.

Comment: @JonClements I'd link an example but that question has been deleted. Perhaps as a mod you can go through my history of asked meta questions even though they have been deleted? There was one some month ago about clearing up a C and C++ canonical duplicate, which was shot down because a gold badge user didn't like it.

Comment: @Lundin you can do that yourself by searching: `user:me is:q closed:1 deleted:1`...

Comment: Here we go then: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360720/cleaning-up-a-canonical-post-about-the-format-of-main-c-and-c. Regardless of if people agreed with the content or not, the discussion was immediately closed, followed by bandwagon-voting.

Comment: @BDL It might be because anti-democratic censoring and elitism upsets me? I don't care about votes, obviously crashing into a clique and accusing that clique for clique-behavior isn't going to be popular.

Comment: _"This is anti-democratic, it is elitism and a form of abuse."_ Well there goes your credibility. An emotionally charged "argument" like that doesn't do _anything_ to strengthen your stance.

Comment: @Lundin By mentioning anti-democratic censoring and elitism you imply that they are at work here. I don't believe that is the case.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the extremely small set of users that can dupe-hammer questions here, __can also re-open them__. Incorrectly closed dupes are __extremely easy__ to get re-opened. _Especially_ when gold badge owners get involved.

Comment: About your edit: _"Supposedly because said user did not wish to discuss it."_ Is that so? That user did a lot of discussing in the comments. That question is saying a lot of the answers are NAA, while they are in fact answers. Perfectly valid closure.

Comment: You have asked **two** questions that were dupe-hammered, with the one you link to deleted. You disagree with the closure of the deleted post, and appear to attribute the downvotes and the closure to elitism and an unwillingness to discuss things. That's not a lot of data to base your feature request on, and you *could* be incorrect in your assessment as to why people voted. Do you have any less biased, emotionally charged evidence that the dupe hammer is being used incorrectly? There is a [weekly database dump you can query](https://data.stackexchange.com/) if you need to mine for data.

Comment: @Lundin: "*Regardless of if people agreed with the content or not, the discussion was immediately closed, followed by bandwagon-voting.*" That's the whole point of marking a question as a duplicate. From your comments on other questions, it seems clear that you seem to think that duplicates "age" or something, that if a Meta dupe target is too old, it is somehow no longer relevant. That is not the case, either on the main site or Meta. A dupe is a dupe; unless you can give justification for why your duplicate needs to exist, then it shouldn't.

Comment: @NicolBolas Of course they age, this is a community-moderated site and the community is ever-changing. Furthermore the site is continuously developed. What was true in 2009 is not necessarily true now. Just go look at the Q&A from when the site is started, and note how lax the site standards were then. Over time, SO has gone from "random stuff about programming" to "Q&A for professionals and enthusiasts" to "interactive beginner tutorial". This ageing _of course_ true on the main site as well, as technologies develop over time.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, some things have changed.  But lots of things haven't; in fact, not nearly as much has changed as people seem to think. If you're able to explain why you think past resolutions of a proposal are different, explaining what is now different that makes the previous conclusions no longer correct, or bringing new points to the table that aren't addressed in earlier discussions, then that's fine, and your post is no longer a duplicate.  But the fact that a post is a year or two old isn't, in and of itself a reason to re-post the exact same question.

Comment: As a veteran you probably know dupe hammer wielders are pingable on the question. If you see me abuse my hammer, feel free to @-reply me and I'm happy to share my reasoning so we can work out if I made a mistake. That is maybe a bit of friction for you but I don't recall I have been far off in my judgement so I'm a bit reluctant to hand back the privilege where there is yet so little evidence I get it wrong all the time,

Comment: @rene What did you think I did? Did you read the link posted?

Comment: Yea, you _did_ ping the closer, but in that ping you immediately validated the closure by confirming you're not up-to-speed with what "NAA" means on SO: _"@Servy If it doesn't answer the question, how is it not a NAA? Did you even read the post? Did you read the original post? I'm impressed that you managed all of this in 2 minutes!"_ The passive-aggressive tone doesn't help, either. In the end, there was no Mjölnir abuse. You also failed to take any _proper_ action to get the question re-opened. No edits, just a argument between two users.

Answer (score 31):

There are [24 gold tag badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold). Discounting users with a diamond (who have veto votes no matter what), today there are:

- [Eleven non-moderator users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/100/discussion) with a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) hammer
- [Three non-moderator users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/109/support) with the [support](/questions/tagged/support) hammer

The latter 3 are a subset of the first 11. So there are **only eleven community members** that can hammer a discussion post as a duplicate (one of these earned the hammer while an employee, another is an ex-moderator). These eleven people have a very long track record with Meta, and I have yet to see any issues with their use of the hammer. And this is *exactly* what a dupe hammer is *for*, not for 'technical' issues, but for **domain knowledge**. These eleven people have domain knowledge, how Stack Overflow and how Meta Stack Overflow works, in droves.

For the other two mandatory tags, there is not going to be any non-moderator account to hold a hammer for quite some time to come. Both [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) are rather specialised tags and are mostly answered by employees and moderators anyway.

You can always flag a post for moderator consideration if (after making sure your question has been clearly differentiated from the duplicate) you still feel your post was unfairly hammered.

However, I don't see any issues with posts that cover the same old ground, again and again and again, being closed. If you really want to revisit an older discussion, **make it clear why it is worth revisiting**.

Unfortunately, there are a lot of new Meta visitors that don't even realise they are revisiting old ground in the first place, haven't done their research, and having a few experienced hands around to help clean up yet another discussion on commenting-when-downvoting or how-SO-is-not-friendly-to-newbies with nothing new to add, is *really really welcome*. And if we ever see actual abuse of the hammer, us moderators can deal with the individual abuser, there is no need to do away with the dupe hammer on Meta based solely on the potential for abuse.

---

To address your specific example, while I understand you wanted to help clean up a big post, you *did* misunderstand what the NAA flag is for or what moderators would generally get involved with. I really don't see any evidence that the community tried to stifle discussion on the matter, your post was visible and active for more than a month before it was automatically cleaned up by the system.

You could have edited the post to re-focus the discussion to see if there was traction in the community to delete specific answers outside the NAA / low quality path, or if there were other ways to approach cleaning up the post. Just like on the main site, edited posts enter a re-open queue, automatically, and [different community members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747254/python-brute-force-algorithm/11747419#11747419) would have been able to vote to reopen.

Instead, you entered a long discussion on why you felt the NAA flags should apply anyway, which is old ground and the dupe target was the correct post to point you to.

Comment: What the OP seems to forget is that those Mjölnir owners can also re-open improperly closed dupes. If one of [the eleven](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0240772/) were to go rogue, there are ten users that can fix it quickly, next to ordinary re-open votes and moderator actions.

Comment: @Cerbrus also: CMs and the site mods peruse meta frequently anyway...

Comment: *there is not going to be any non-moderator account to hold a hammer for quite some time to come.* ... but [tag:bug] is on my tag-badge tracker ... I'll get there, eventually. Just so I can dupe-hammer all the thingz ....

Comment: I just need 117 more feature request answers :D

Comment: +9000 for "You could have edited the post to re-focus the discussion" - the post is indeed duplicate *as asked*, but perfectly good question if asked "looking for help/guidance (I know that NAA not an option and moderators generally not involved in such requests)". This is exactly we want to happen for duplicates...