# Flagging an off-topic question with bounty for moderator attention is currently impossible

Tags: bug, scope, abuse

I ran across an [off-topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49671941/is-there-an-implementation-to-receive-rather-than-send-web-notifications-in-an) today (asking to recommend a tool for a task) and tried to close it, but it had an active bounty. So my next thought is: hey, this is an abuse.

Searching on a subject, I found this has already happened and was [talked about](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252192/how-can-i-close-a-question-that-has-an-active-bounty) before. According to the accepted answer there, I'm supposed to flag the question for moderator attention.

However, that's impossible, if I select the correct options. I could probably try to "trick" the system and search for a way to pass a message to a moderator, explaining the situation, but I thought the right thing to do is report it here as a standing system bug (which I believe it is).

Here's the list of steps I tried to follow and (IMHO) should work:

- press flag
- select "**should be closed**"
- select "**off-topic because...**"
- select "Questions asking us to recommend or find **a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

The 4-th step results into a toaster message:

> This question has an open bounty and cannot be closed

, which is the message one gets when trying to close the question (directly, without flagging). This response **cancels both closing and flagging**.

Selecting the closing reason while flagging for moderator attention should not be blocked by the same routine preventing closing a bounty bearing question.

---

**Note**: I took the liberty of adding the [abuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abuse) tag as, currently, adding a bounty to an off-topic question is a way of abusing the current state of the system.

**Note**: The correct *"answer"* to this question is, IMHO, changing the logic of flagging for moderator attention for this type of questions. I am not looking for ways to "trick" the system into getting moderator's attention. Doing so would mean I practice and promote the same type of thinking and actions as the original question poster (which is what we're trying to avoid) which is, IMHO, abusive. I just thought this should be reported and fixed.

Comment: You need to raise a _custom_ mod flag. That's what is says in the accepted answer to the question you linked.

Comment: just press flag > **in need of moderator intervention** > explain the question is bountied but should be closed with the reasons why you think closing is needed.

Comment: @rene I see. But, don't you agree the routine for selecting the proper reason **inside** flagging should not be prevented and should not result into actually voting to close the question (if the user reporting the issue has sufficient rep to close it)?

Comment: I don't see why questions should be exempted from close votes because of a bounty, and given the size of the moderator queues as it is, I don't see why the community can't deal with it.

Comment: In any case... this is not a _bug_. It's either a support question or a feature request.

Comment: @JoeC, that's a different discussion and I'm not willing to discuss it. I just wanted to apply currently "*agreed upon rules*". And, by choosing what seemed to be the most appropriate option at each step, I ran into a block. I thought I should ask if this is a bug or if it was intended. It certainly feels like a bug. I'm prevented to do action B because action A is not possible.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu No, I don't agree because although it might *fix* the question staying open it doesn't get rid of the bounty and I've seen cases where the bounty was simply forcibly ended or where it was refunded. Adding that in the close vote flow will take 6 to 8 weeks to design, 6 to 8 weeks  to build and 6 to 8 weeks to test. Given the rare cases this really causes friction the extra mod flag wouldn't hurt the mod queue that badly, me thinks.

Comment: It't not a bug, you can't use regular flags on bountied question. That's working as designed. You are supposed to raise a custom flag.

Comment: @yivi, got it. Thank you very much. I raised a custom flag on the question.

Comment: @yivi, out of curiosity: why do regular flags appear on bountied questions, if they can't be used? Is hiding them deemed as *"not worth the development effort"*?

Comment: I reckon that for the same reason the voting buttons appear in your own posts. UI consistency and development effort.

Comment: @yivi that's pretty much it. Same as why up/downvote arrows appear next to your own questions/answers even though you can't use them.

Comment: If those flags _didn't_ appear on bountied questions, we'd get meta posts asking why. At least like this, you get a self-documenting response about why you can't use them.

Comment: Understood and thank you, both. But perhaps the message appearing on the above sequence should be changed to *"You can't use regular flags on bountied questions"* rather than the message for which the question can't be closed. Agreed? Point being: i needed to research this in order to find it out, it wasn't clear in the info the system gave me in the question I was trying to close.