# Is there a way to voluntarily migrate my question with a bounty to the site I should've actually asked?

Tags: support, bounty, migration

Stack Overflow being the first site of the SE gamma to come to existence, has a lot of questions that don't relate to programming, I got confused and posted my question here. But now that I know better, I'd like to move my question to 'Server Fault'.

Is voluntarily closing it and asking again the only option?

Comment: Not at all. I'm just asking a fair question.

Comment: @RobertLongson Given the circumstances, _I'd guess_ that b is faster, given that it doesn't require to wait for the bounty to expire. Ultimately, it depends on mods availability being higher or lower than the bounty expire time, so no definite answer. No need to be snarky.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50223593/openstack-stable-queens-branch-dashboard-not-responding-after-successful-instal) currently has a bounty on it. To close or delete it you'll have to either

1. Wait for the bounty period to expire as bountied questions [can't be closed or deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/284336)
2. Get a diamond moderator to cancel the bounty... which is unlikely as moderators aren't generally supposed to cancel bounties unless in extreme cases. This would be their call, though.

Once the question is off bounty, I recommend deleting it yourself and then asking it on the other site directly. This requires no work from anyone other than yourself and it's immediate. It also saves the risk of it being closed for being posted in multiple places at once.

If someone *answers* the question and the answer is upvoted, you won't be able to delete the question yourself, so you'll have to get the question closed/deleted by the users.

Answer (score 7):

The question was not a good fit for Stack Overflow.
In response to your meta post:
The bounty has been removed.
The question has been closed and deleted.

Feel free to post the question on a site that is more ontopic - being mindful of the acceptable post rules for that site.

Next time [post a custom mod flag on such a post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252192/how-can-i-close-a-question-that-has-an-active-bounty). If a question is off topic, it's acceptable for any member of the community to flag for the bounty to be removed so the question can be closed. This does not mean the flag will be marked as helpful, only if the question is off topic.

In terms of migrating posts, we're reluctant to migrate posts, unless they're clearly off topic for here and a good quality post for the target site. It's important to be mindful (as you've noted in your post) that being on topic elsewhere does not automatically preclude it being on topic here.