# Why are flags not allowed on questions with bounties?

Tags: discussion, flags, bounty

Flags are not allowed on questions with bounties. This allows high-reputation question owners to stop their question from being closed or deleted when in some cases the questions aren't clear, or are too broad.

Why is this? Shouldn't questions be treated equally?

If there's a bad question that deserves to be flagged, even with a bounty on it, I think that you should be allowed to flag it.

The specific question in question is: [How to reliably reproduce curl_multi timeout while testing public proxies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54827396/how-to-reliably-reproduce-curl-multi-timeout-while-testing-public-proxies)

I'd previously flagged it before, however, the flag was declined: [My Flags page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/10795151?showDeclined=true)

Comment: It's important to note that "close" flags aren't allowed on bountied questions, just like close votes aren't. The other flags should work. Also, we normal users can't see your flags page.

Comment: True, but that question really is out-of-scope for SO. There's no clear solution, and it's also not very clear exactly what the OP is asking (especially with all the unnecessary details included).

Comment: If a bountied question has an issue, flag for a moderator, state that it currently has a bounty and explain why it needs to be removed. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252192/how-can-i-close-a-question-that-has-an-active-bounty

Comment: Thanks. Will do. It's nice how the answers to your question show up *after* you actually post it :).