# User vandalizes and deletes a question with close votes, then repost question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

A user asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56026692/issues-with-string) which had received 3 close votes as opinion-based.  The user responded  with a comment objecting to the close votes, then by vandalizing the question and deleting it.

They then [repost the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56026896/can-having-wildcard-strings-in-a-tables-column-create-issues).  This effectively removed the close votes from the question, preventing the usual moderation mechanisms from operating.

What is the correct way of handling this particular situation?

Edit:

Elevating comment to the question for visibility:

> I wasn't going to bring this up, but it has become relevant. I do not believe this is the first instance I've come across. I remember one other delete-then-repost, and I'm sure it was the same user (I recognize the avatar). However, I cannot remember what that question was, so I cannot be certain it was the same user. It was over a month ago.

Comment: Maybe a moderator flag but the user could be shooting themselves in the foot if the question should be closed. Deleted questions still count against them toward the ban so deleting and reposting just to get down and close votes on a second question might be a problem that takes care of itself.

Comment: My concern is less that the question should be closed (I did vote to close), but that the moderation systems are being preventing from functioning.  If the duplicate received 3 more close votes, what prevents them from repeating the exercise with a fresh question repeatedly?  Effectively, the user is unilaterally exercising veto power over close votes on their own question, and can do so repeatedly.

Comment: @Amy - The question ban prevents that from being an option very quickly. In addition, I believe there are also automated triggers for deleting too many questions in a short time frame.

Comment: @fbueckert I wasn't going to bring this up, but it has become relevant.  I do not believe this is the first instance I've come across.  I remember one other delete-then-repost, and I'm sure it was the same user (I recognize the avatar).  However, I cannot remember what that question was, so I cannot be certain it was the same user.  It was over a month ago.

Comment: @Amy Perfect thing to mention to moderators.  They can see that, and take action as required.

Comment: @fbueckert Okay. I did flag as suggested, and pointed the mods to this question. I'll elevate my comment to the question so it can be seen.

Comment: (It's my question that the post is about) Just to inform everyone; I've admitted my mistake and apologized for it. I now know better and will not repeat such behavior again. Mods have also reached out to me and handled the case appropriately.

Comment: So, since it's still too broad, why hasn't the bounty been removed and the post outright closed now per [How can I close a question that has an active bounty?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252192/691711) and [Why cannot this question with an open bounty be closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199190/251625)?

Comment: @zero298 It stayed over a day with 0 close votes after it had been edited and it had gotten 5 reopen votes. If it should've been closed again it had plenty of time to get even one close vote.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You raise a custom moderator flag, presenting the evidence that you presented here.

A moderator then follows up in response to your flag, cleaning up the mess and reaching out to the user to inform them that intentionally circumventing the quality-control mechanisms that are in place here is not acceptable.

The entire process is anonymous (to everyone but moderators), which avoids you becoming the target of revenge downvoting or any other sort of nastiness.

Comment: Would that cause the moderator to get revenge downvotes instead?

Comment: Uh, depends on how it's done. Certain private channels of communication with a user maintain the anonymity of the individual moderator who wrote the message. But revenge downvotes are a common occupational hazard of being a moderator, as are death threats. We have tools to handle some of these, and others we just deal with for the good of the community. Better that the aggression be targeted at moderators than at regular users. That's what we're here for. @EJoshuaS

Comment: Really? Death threats? That actually happens?

Comment: Yes, it has happened several times. That sort of abuse, and more, was what led to [the anonymization of moderator messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283725/make-moderator-messages-anonymous). The comments and answers there have several references to the type of abuse that moderators regularly experience, even including off-site harassment. I regularly get threatening emails because anyone with half a brain cell can deduce my email from my profile. In fact, it seems complaints and worse are the *only* emails I ever get from Stack Overflow members.

Comment: Anyone who would react that way to a suspension presumably thoroughly deserved it.

Comment: *"In fact, it seems complaints and worse are the only emails I ever get from Stack Overflow members."* That sounds like a challenge. I hope you're ready for pictures of puppies ;)

Comment: An off-topic conversation where [Ole complains about tyrannical moderators](https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/one-month-in-the-stackoverflow-pentalty-box-d38cb4021c0c) has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193108/discussion-on-answer-by-cody-gray-user-vandalizes-and-deletes-a-question-with-cl).

Comment: After I read @CodyGray 's comment last night, I was tempted to send him pictures of kittens.