# Off-topic bounty questions

Tags: discussion, flags, specific-question, vote-to-close, bounty

Bounty questions cannot be closed (by users). This feels to me like a way to open an off-topic question and protect it from being closed. I have seen multiple questions recently that would need to be closed but could not.

In all cases, I flag them for moderator attention with a message similar than the below one, which I believe summarizes my opinion on the matter:

*Does the fact that a question has an open bounty allow the question to be off-topic? I believe it should not be the case. This question should be closed as it is not about programming, but about the use of a third party service, but can't be close because of the bounty which IMO is a non-sense. Please close this question as it does NOT follow SO rules. Thank you.*

In most cases, moderators took action and closed the question.

That said, I have flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56711504/google-maps-api-http-restrictions-how-to-use-wildcards) on June 25. (with the same message) and my flag was marked as "helpful" but nothing happened. The question is still open, and as far as I can tell, the bounty has been awarded.

Question: **How can a flag be marked as helpful and no action be taken?**

And as a more general question, should SO not simply allow bounty question to be closed?

**Edit**: This is not a duplicate of [How can I close a question that has an active bounty?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252192/how-can-i-close-a-question-that-has-an-active-bounty) which is asking **how** to close a question with an open bounty, which I was already aware of.

Comment: The mod may want to mark your flag as "helpful" so it doesn't reflect badly on your flagging stats, and yet not be completely convinced an action is necessary despite appreciating your intent. Or other factors (as existing answers posted under the bounty) may make them reluctant to remove the bounty and close the question.

Comment: Right. I am used to see moderators' comments when the action (or no action) needs an explanation but this time there was none. I understand your comment, but quite disagree with it. Are you saying that if an off-topic question gets answered, it then becomes on-topic?

Comment: I haven't said anything of the sort.

Comment: No... You didn't say that with these words but you said *other factors (as existing answers posted under the bounty) may make them reluctant to remove the bounty and close the question* ... did I misunderstand that part of your comment then? To me, an off-topic question is off-topic. Even if it has 20 up-votes and 20 answers.

Comment: If you understood it as "off-topic answered questions become on-topic", yes, you misunderstood it. I only meant that sometimes a mod can be reluctant to remove a bounty from a question with active answers.

Comment: Ok, but then why? If it is off-topic, then it should be closed. Or at least, this is how I thought SO works. Here I am not only talking about removing the bounty, but closing the question (which I believe implies removing the bounty).

Comment: We already have covered the “why” before here on meta and on Uber-meta:  because bounties are a special case where you can easily get a yo-yo effect, a tug of war when a lot of different users are seeing the post and may subsequently close and reopen the post several times. So this is relegated to moderators instead.

Comment: Moderators can always mark post flags as helpful without taking action. We do that when we feel the flagging was appreciated but we didn’t think any specific action was necessary. I’ll ping the mod in question to see if they want to give more specific reasonings.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for that. I understand it better now. Until now I had never seen a helpful flag of mine being handled that way. And so I will continue to flag that kind of questions in the same way.

Comment: @gnat it is not a duplicate of this question. I know I can flag it for moderation. My questions were 1) why was there no action although my flag was marked as helpful, and 2) **why** can we not close bounty questions (not how).

Comment: these are two questions really.

Comment: @MartijnPieters perhaps post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm only addressing your helpful flag.

I marked the flag as helpful, as it was an understandable thing to flag, as it's referring to an API that can be construed as a third-party tool. I didn't agree that it needed to be closed, but actually it's fair to ask this as a programming question.

#### My reasons for declining flags is to teach people how to flag.

If a person is raising a moderator flag when a standard flag will do, I'll usually decline it. In this case it's fair to question the validity of closing a question that has a bounty via a moderator flag, as only moderator s can remove the bounty. As a rule of thumb I rarely if ever decline these, as it's not something I want to discourage people from doing.

Comment: Understood and mostly agreed although I still think this question (this kind of questions) should be closed. But thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Interesting how slightly different philosophies on the reasons for declining flags can lead to vastly different outcomes. For example, you decline flags to teach people how to flag, so you’d decline something where a standard flag exists, but mark as helpful a procedurally valid flag even where you took no action. Instead, if your decline was based on net outcome (or helpfulness towards improving the site), you’d mark the first as helpful (even though the wrong flag type was raised, action still needed to be taken) and decline the second (as it did not bring important info to mod attention).

Comment: I agree with Yvette here regarding this question. I would not have closed it. I struggle to understand why you think it is off-topic. It is a usage question about an API. It’s not asking someone to recommend or find an API, and specific questions about programmatic usage of APIs have always been on-topic here. What aspect of this makes it seem like not a programming question to you, @mru?

Comment: @MrUpsidown I've investigated both your flags and the user and they do indeed work for Google. Quit targeting them and maligning them. Can I make myself any clearer? Part of the reason I didn't decline this flag is I was handling your other flags and I didn't want to go on a declining flag spree. I didn't mention it in the answer as your flags are confidential, but you brought them up publicly.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Was that a reason for deleting my previous comment? It was an answer to Cody Gray who asked me a question. You can't make it any clearer. Discussion is over. I am not targeting/maligning anyone, I am just trying to prevent product support to happen on SO which is the point you won't let me make. I will continue flagging such questions anyway until I am fed up with SO and/or reactions like yours and the inability to discuss any topic here without getting flamed at. Have a nice day.

Comment: @MrUpsidown it is **not** ok to malign someone and state you don't believe they work for a company they have in their profile. You flagged it and you had a reply, the person does indeed work for Google and it's OK for Google to offer support on here. Many other organisations refer people to Stack Overflow, it's better if they have a team on here offering support, which they do in this API. You're not being flamed at, you're being told clearly do **not** make accusations at people.

Comment: *Which they do*... wrongly, that's still my opinion, and only very recently then because until this user started answering (off-topic) questions, there were basically very few people watching this tag, closing and/or flagging inappropriate questions on a daily basis (**and** answering the good ones!). Whether or not it is true that someone actually works at Google or not doesn't make much difference. But I have learned something today: Product support is OK on SO even if it doesn't involve programming.

Comment: @MrUpsidown that is a valid and separate discussion. I have no issue with your points on that. Just be mindful about how you're going about getting that point across. I think this should be a separate discussion, whether these API questions are on topic for SO.

Comment: This is agreed!