# Duplicate question has an open bounty

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, bounty

As you can see, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59868022/5675325) is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4273252/5675325).

We can't close it though because it has an open bounty but we could go there and write one of the answers there.

Thought about flag to get attention from a moderator but didn't want to disturb them with this without knowing such situation should be given to them. What's the best thing to do in this situation?

Also, should the person addressing this (me, in this case) be awarded with the bounty?

Comment: More importantly, the only answer to the first question is plagiated from the other question's answer (and from the source stated there)

Comment: I don't understand: you want to get the bounty for finding out that the question is a dupe???

Comment: Why not @yivi? If the bounty vanishes. I understand one of the reasons why not -> then we could stop marking as dupe and only do it when a bounty comes up (even though the likelihood of that to happen is very very low I think).

Comment: Well, just FYI: You won't get the bounty. The result of flagging such a question is get the bounty removed and the question dupe-closed. And, in this particular case, get the plagiarism handled.

Comment: Well, I tried and now I know. Do I still need to flag for moderator attention?

Comment: (just did anyways)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252193/5675325)

> A bounty on a post doesn't exempt it from being off-topic.

So, **it has to be closed**. If that's what we ought to do, then there's a [specific question for that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252192/5675325) where the answer tells us to flag as *in need of moderator intervention* with the something within the following lines

> This question is a duplicate, but I cannot VtC it as such because
>   there is a bounty on it. Can a moderator please remove the bounty?

In regards with me receiving the bounty (or even part of it), yivi affirms in the comments

> You won't get the bounty. The result of flagging such a question is
>   get the bounty removed and the question dupe-closed. And, in this
>   particular case, get the plagiarism handled.

Not sure if this means the bounty goes back to the person giving the bounty in the first place or it simply vanishes.