# Flagging off-topic bounty questions?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I thought that flagging was the way to go when I want to close an off-topic question that has a bounty since it can't be closed.

[How can we close questions with bounties?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-can-we-close-questions-with-bounties)

So why was my flag declined here with a message of *Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags*? It's blatantly off-topic, not reproducible, too broad, etc.

[Google Distance Matrix API does not allow additional requests even though billing is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46652643)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You never told us there was a bounty on the post. This was your flag:

> Not reproducible, no code, about an external service, too broad, unclear. Not for SO.

Moderators have a flag dashboard that shows a lot of info but not that a post has a bounty. As such, your flag looked like any of the ~20-40 flags we get every day telling us a post isn’t suitable, and we declined it for that reason.

I’ve now removed the bounty and closed the post. Please, in future *include all pertinent details*. Don’t just tell us that the post is bad, also tell us why you need our intervention and what you need us to do. See [this answer of mine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252192/how-can-i-close-a-question-that-has-an-active-bounty/252193#252193) for an example.